# Error during document enrichment. Details: "The language of the document could not be identified."

Tags: node.js, watson, watson-discovery

I'm trying to index a document on Discovery, but one of the documents is causing this error:

```
Error during document enrichment. Details: "The language of the document could not be identified."
```

This is the text that I'm trying to convert:

```
Ao tentar emitir uma nota fiscal eletrônica o sistema apresenta a seguinte mensagem: Informar email no cadastro de clientes.
Acessar o cadastro do cliente no qual está emitindo a nota fiscal eletrônica, na aba Complementares e informar o e-mail do cliente no campo E-Mail.
```

And this is my indexing function:

```
function indexDocument(doc) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        discovery.addDocument({         
            environment_id: config.watson.environment_id,
            collection_id: config.watson.collection_id,
            file: {
                value: JSON.stringify(doc),
                options: {
                    filename: 'ocorrencia_' + doc.ocorrencia_id + '.json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                }
            }
        }, (error, data) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Does someone know why this problem is occurring? Is there a way to directly specify the language when indexing a document on Discovery?

Answer (score 2):

Discovery's handling of language was enhanced mid-2017. My best guess is that you are using a `version_date` string of some date earlier than mid-2017. Can you try using the most recent `version_date` of `2017-11-07`? With the earlier `version_date` Discovery attempts to auto-detect the language, which has several deficiencies. With more recent `version_date` values, the language specified on each collection is used as the assigned language for enrichments.

Comment: Specifically, you want to use a version date of `2017-06-25` or later. Later is better as you'll get a more recent (with more fixes) version of the API.